# Detect whether an HTML element was inserted by a browser extension

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I want to build a JS based solution that will help to detect injected ads into a page. This JS payload will get served with each ad impression and try to detect whether the ad slot was organically placed or was injected by a browser extension.

For those who are not very familiar with online advertisement fraud techniques ad injection is a technique where an ad is injected into a webpage by some malicious browser plugin or extension.

I have looked into [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) APIs to detect DOM insertions. But I am not able to find a way to determine that the HTML element was injected through some browser extension.

Is it possible to determine whether a [Mutation Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) was caused by a browser extension?

Comment: Do you want to A) warn the user? B) prevent them injecting stuff to you page? If the answer is B then have a look at [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP) headers

Comment: I want to report such occurrences to a logging server. Since I am not owner of the page, I will not be able to set CSP headers. Please correct me if I am wrong ?

Comment: You can still add CSP header if the site is using https - using service worker. But since you want to report such behaviour, you should then use MutationObserver, and you need to figure out by yourself when it was you who modified the DOM